Wix forms triggered email issue
The backend is work correctly and I get status code 200 and also get a response with callId number.
The problem is that the contact don't get the email.
I tried to run it on publish but still not working, another thing is that the contactId is undefined and I don't know why.
import { submitServiceCallBackend } from 'backend/formHandler';
import { triggeredEmails, contacts } from 'wix-crm-frontend';

$w.onReady(function () {
    $w('#submitButton').onClick(() => {
        $w('#message').text = 'Submitting...';
        $w('#submitButton').disable();

        const formData = {
            Token: "TestServiceCall",
            LicTradNum: $w('#license').value,
            Subject: $w('#subject').value,
            Description: $w('#description').value,
            ContactPersonEmail: $w('#email').value,
            ContactPersonName: $w('#name').value,
            ContactPersonPhone: $w('#phone').value
        };
        console.log('Submitting form data:', formData);

        submitServiceCallBackend(formData)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Response received:', response);
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    const callId = response.data.callId;
                    console.log('Success:', response.data);

            $w('#message').text = `Thanks for submitting, your service Call ID is${callId}`;

                    contacts.appendOrCreateContact({
                        name: {
                            first: $w("#name").value,
                        },
                        extendedFields: {
                            callId: callId,
                        },
                    })
                    .then((contactInfo) => {
                        const contactId = contactInfo.contactId;
                        console.log("contact id:", contactId);
                        console.log('Contact created/updated:', contactInfo);

                        triggeredEmails.emailContact("serviceCallForm", contactId, {
                            variables: {
                                name: $w("#name").value,
                                callId: callId,
                            },
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log("Email sent");
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.error("Failed to send email", error);
                        });
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error("Failed to create/update contact", error);
                    });
                } else {
                    $w('#message').text = 'Submission failed. Please try again later.';
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Catch block error:', error);
                $w('#message').text = 'Submission failed. Please try again later.';
            })
            .finally(() => {
                console.log('Request completed');
                $w('#submitButton').enable();
            });
    });
});

